# ajaxStop of different .js file getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a two .js file with ajxStop() in them.

```
1.js

 $(document).ajaxStop(function() {

            //doingSomething
 });

2.js

 $(document).ajaxStop(function() {

            //doingSomethingelse
 });
```

I want ajaxStop() of 1.js to be called instead if 2.js . How can I achieve it?

Comment: Because it is global....  If it is just supposed to be for a single call, than build it into the Ajax call itself and not bind to all Ajax Calls.

Comment: remove second js